# Parametrizing a sub query with jdbc PreparedStatement

Tags: jdbc

I have the following query where the first argument itself is a subquery

The java code is:

```
String query = select * from (?) where ROWNUM < ?
PreparedStatement statement = conn.preparedStatement(query)
statement.setString(1, "select * from foo_table")
statement.setInt(2, 3)
```

When I run the java code, I get an exception. What alternatives do I have for making the first subquery `statement.setString(1, "select * from foo_table")` a parameter?

Comment: You cannot pass a sub-query as a parameter in a `PreparedStatement`. You need to concatenate the SQL into a single String

Comment: _Why_ would you want to pass in the subquery as a parameter?

Comment: To avoid SQL injection

Comment: Do you mean that these subqueries are written by users?

Comment: That's the issue, the subquery itself is coming from outside source and is a parameter to the method

Comment: If an (untrusted) outside source is providing these queries, then there is really no way to prevent SQL injection other than perhaps using some kind of SQL parser for sanitizing the query. Is there any way that you could expose a different kind of API for custom queries -- one that would not use custom SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, parameter placeholders can only represent values, not object names (like table names, column names, etc) nor subselects or other query elements.

You will need to dynamically create the query to execute using string concatenation, or other string formatting/templating options.